# jquery dynamic radio button validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created 20 radio button dynamically

```
 <script>

$(function() {

    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({

        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"

    }).disableSelection();

    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({

       remove: function(event, ui) { 

           t = ui.item[0].attributes['id'].nodeValue;


          k = $("input[name='"+t+"' ]");


          k.remove();

       },


       receive: function(event, ui) { 

           //itemid = ui.item[0].attributes['id'];

        t = ui.item[0].attributes['id'].nodeValue;   
        $("#element").append( "<br/>" +ui.item[0].innerHTML.trim() );
            for(i=1; i<=20; i++)
            { 
                j=$("#over" + i).append("<br/> <td><input type=radio name='"+ui.item[0].innerHTML.trim()+"' value='"+i+"'></td> <br/>");
               var radVal=$("#over" + i+":checked").val();
  alert(radVal);
            }

}


    });        

});
```

` 'Player';

for($j=1;$j<=20;$j++)

{

```
echo '<th align="center">'.$j.'</th>';
```

}

echo '';

echo "";
{
   echo ""; 
echo "";
echo "";

for($i = 1; $i <=20; $i++)
        {
        echo "";
        echo "";
        echo "";
        }
  }
  echo "";

?>    `

my question is that how to check validation value

Comment: depends how you validate it..

Comment: Also depends (what) your validating.  Are you validating other fields depending on the radio button that has been selected?

Comment: could you post your code for generated form???

Comment: you need to write the code `$("input[name=nameOfRadiobuttons]:checked").val()` once there is radio button checked, writing it in the `while loop` won't work...need to call a function to check this...call a function with  the `$("input[name=nameOfRadiobuttons]:checked").val()` in it on the click of a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code where you generate the radiobutton to: (Add the value attribute)

```
<input type=radio name='"+ui.item[0].innerHTML.trim()+"' value='"+i+"'>
```

After adding all the radio button if you call this function on any click event

```
function getChecked(){
     var radVal=$("input[name=nameOfRadiobuttons]:checked").val();

     alert(radVal);
}
```

Put a button on th HTML Page calling the function

```
<input type=button onclick='getChecked()'>
```

radVal will give the index of the checkbox selected..If its undefined then you might not have checked any radio button

Comment: still problem undefined radio button

Comment: Please can you post the code that you executed...I have edited my post a bit...have a look at it...

Comment: what is the value of the name attribute of the radio buttons?

Comment: `var radVal=$("input[name=nameOfRadiobuttons]:checked").val();

 alert(radVal);` needs to be executed separately not inside the while loop as you have done call this on an click event of a function

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = $('#over1:checked').val();
```

or

```
 var temp = $('#over1').val();
```

Comment: when I check this validation I got 1 error that is "UNDEFINE"

Comment: use variable that you are using for looping
var temp = $('#over' + i +':checked').val();

Comment: radio button values will be always true as value of radio button i.e. "i" is > 0