# how to create dynamic radio button in jQuery with it's validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have compose one small application in which I want to add 20 radio buttons and then validate whether radio button check or not. Please give me some hints.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery dynamic radio button validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562001/jquery-dynamic-radio-button-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('input:checked')` will return all checked radio buttons.. From here you can do some validation, i guess..